# /dev/video0 not created

Tags: v4l2

I am having trouble getting a USB Camera to work with a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B. I cannot get /dev/video0 to be created. I have run sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2 and I can see bcm2835-v4l2 when I run lsmod but there is still no /dev/video0. Where am I going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What make / model of Camera is it?

Comment: It is a IDS uEye XC.

Comment: Maybe check this link out - looks like IDS have a driver available for the armv7.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16883611/setting-up-ueye-camera-for-raspberry-pi i'd would summise the driver is not in the kernel hence not populating the device node. The Pdf on the link in the SO answer details the steps on a Pi so i think this might be a good place to start.

Comment: I have already downloaded the driver and unpacked it successfully. This is probably a dumb question as I am new to Linux but how do I check and see if it is in the Kernel? I appreciate the help

Comment: By the looks of it, you have to run up a utility (page 5 of the IDS embedded instructions pdf) which gets it all going. I'm not too sure what to expect from this though. Once you've run the setup script as root (its not clear if this is `sudo` or actually as root `sudo su`) I'd guess it all becomes clear ( ish :) ). Once installed you can check `lsmod` to see if an IDS driver has appeared, also `lsusb` to check what the OS thinks of the usb devices in the system.

Comment: I do not see anything with IDS or uEye or SDK when I run lsmod. When I run the last step "/etc/init.d/ueyeusbdrc start" it returns "starting ueyeusbd...ueyeusbd is already running". Does that mean that it is working?

Comment: I'd say thats working, or at least as well as you can expect from the docs - do you have the /dev/videoX node now? That would seem to be the proof its ok? If you have v4l2 installed you could run `v4l2-ctl --list-devices` to see if it thinks its a device it can talk to.

Comment: Still no /dev/video0. v4l2-ctl --list-devices doesnt work. Returns "failed to open /dev/video0: no such directory or file"

Comment: You'll probably need to have a read through IDCs docs (check that install bundle for a readme) or try running up the GUI Manager they provide (if you have a desktop environment) to work out what it going on. It might not expose the camera as a v4l2 device hence that not working / no node. Its a bit more a specialised device that just a simple camera. https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/908171/jetson-tk1/issue-for-ids-ueye-camera-with-jetson-tk1/ its a few months old but seems to suggest IDC don't do a V4L2 driver at the moment - this is the likely cause for no /dev/video0 node.

Comment: OK I will get digging again. Thank you very much for your time and your help @tobyd